# Fortigate Firewall cli query || show and get

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

which type information can be seen by executing keywords "GET" and "SHOW" with combination other keywords at Fortigate firewall cli in general way. Can anyone differentiate the information print by using these keywords.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can remember show is used to check parameters and options as they are set in configuration, while get is used to check runtime values. Let say you have configured an interface for autonegotiation. You can see this with a show command. When the interface comes up it negotiates 100/full. You can check this with a get command

Comment: Thanks, however show commands display configured CLI by user or pre defined. and Get commands display system accepted/operations parameters/feature of that relative technologies...